# Проблема с методом on()

Tags: jquery, ajax

У меня на аяксе подгружаются значения в `select`, пустой инпут и кнопка с `id="new_section"`. Этих трех элементов формы при загрузке странице, не было в dom.

И теперь, при нажатии на кнопку с `id="new_section"`, я хочу что бы отправлялись значения из селекта и инпута. Но ничего не происходит, во вкладке нетворк пусто. Почему? Ведь метод `on()` используется вместо делегирования и должен работать.

Вот функция:

```
$('#new_section_button').on('click',function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '{{ url('api/section/set') }}',
            data: {
                new_section_name: $('#new_section_name').val(),
                new_section_val: $('#new_section_val').val()
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#new_section_button', function() { ...`.  "new_section" или "new_section_button"? делЕгирования

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Работает)